# Mastering Blender Chapter 2 Smokestack Activity

Tags: texturing, uv

I recently purchased Mastering Blender, the eBook, and have began Chapter 2. I am currently experiencing difficulty with the Smokestack activity. When I follow steps 1 through 4, I do not get the same Unwrap result as shown in Figure 2-8.

The screenshot provides the instructions for the Smokestack texture project:  [image]

This is a link to the Blender file of my result: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38699.

As you will notice, there are seven parts (versus Figure 2-8's six) and also the smallest part is a closed circle (versus Figure 2-8's semi-circle). I had gotten the result shown in the book on one attempt, however, I had missed a step and had to reattempt the activity and could not achieve the same result. How to match Figure 2-8?

Comment: UV map should be the same, if you placed the seams as the author did and if the model is done also the same. I'd suggest returning to the previous step where seams were setting up.

Comment: You don't have the right seams.  This isn't helped by the fact that in Blender creases are displayed in Pink whilst seams are display in Red.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the UV editor and manually move the separate UVs around. If you select any vertex in one of the pieces and then hit <kbd>L</kbd> on the keyboard every vertex in that island will be selected. You can then use <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate, <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and <kbd>G</kbd> to grab and transform each island. Being able to pack your separate UVs to maximize the available space is a good skill to develop. As to why your UVs aren't the same as the picture? They rarely are. I have had a look at the file and am wondering if you have your seams marked exactly as the example. Maybe you could check that first. Good luck.